# Exclude properties when rendering object as json in grails 2.4.0

Tags: json, grails

I don't understand how can i exclude some properties when rendering an object as JSON in a controller (not a RESTController but a classic Controller).
I have this resources.groovy:

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
import grails.rest.render.json.JsonRenderer
import com.appromocodes.Promocode
import com.appromocodes.ResponseStatus
import grails.rest.render.json.JsonCollectionRenderer

beans = {
    responseStatusRenderer(JsonRenderer, ResponseStatus) {
        excludes = ['enumType']
    }

    promocodeRenderer(JsonRenderer, Promocode) {
        excludes = ['class', 'id', 'project']
    }

}
```

Within my controller i tried in my action something like:

```
respond p as JSON
```

but this still gives me all the fields (also class, id and project fields).

What should i do?

Comment: Why `as Object` and not `as JSON`?

Comment: Sorry i made a type and now i've changed with "as JSON" (it was a typo coming from various tries), but the result is always the same: i always have the class property shown

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle this is to register a custom JSON marshaller for your object. Begin by creating a new Marshaller in `src/groovy/packageName/marshallers/PromocodeMarshaller.groovy` with the following contents:

```
import packageName.Promocode
import grails.converters.JSON

class PromocodeMarshaller {

  void register() {
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Promocode) { promocode ->
      return [
        id: promocode?.id,
        // all the fields you'd like to return
        // in your JSON object 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, inside of your `Bootstrap.groovy` file, include the following:

```
import packageName.marshallers.PromocodeMarshaller

def promodcodeMarshaller = new PromocodeMarshaller()
promocodeMarshaller.register()
```

For a full description, see [this article](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/).